# Same selection query is giving different results in terms of selected records

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio

I have a 3 step automation:

1. Step 1 selects the audience for the journey entry data extension (this overwrites the DE *Offer_Extension_Warmup_Journey_Entry*)
2. Step runs the exact same query but logs the records to a logging data extension (This adds and updates the logging DE *Offer_Extension_Journey_Entry*)
3. Step 3 is the journey to send out the emails.

The query is resulting in different records in step 1 & step 2. I'm not sure what might be causing that.

```
SELECT TOP (1200)
email_address,
first_name,
last_name,
preapproved_amount,
promo_code,
expiry_date = DATEADD (DAY,86,expiry_date)
FROM First_Offer_Journey_Entry
    WHERE (email_address NOT IN (select email_address from Offer_Extension_Journey_Entry))
    AND (email_address NOT IN (select email_address from [Email Addresses from Table A]))
    AND (email_address NOT IN (select email_address from [Email Addresses from Table B]))
    AND (email_address NOT IN (select email_address from [Not-In-Table-B]))
    AND (email_address NOT IN (select SubscriberKey from ent.[HardBounces_DE]))
    AND (email_address NOT IN (select SubscriberKey from ent.[DV_Complaint]))
    AND (email_address NOT IN (select email_address from [Withdrawn_Non-Retargetable]))
    AND (email_address NOT IN (select email_address from [DM Data To be Excluded from OE]))
    AND expiry_date = '7/20/2023 12:00:00 AM'
    AND email_address like '%@gmail.com'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the Journey entry DE receiving records as the queries are running?

If so, you could simply run your second query using the target DE of the first query as the `from` in your second query.

**Query 1**

```sql
SELECT TOP (1200)
  e.email_address
, e.first_name
, e.last_name
, e.preapproved_amount
, e.promo_code
, expiry_date = DATEADD(DAY, 86, e.expiry_date)
FROM First_Offer_Journey_Entry as e
WHERE 1=1
and e.email_address not in (
    
              select email_address from Offer_Extension_Journey_Entry
    union all select email_address from [Email Addresses from Table A]
    union all select email_address from [Email Addresses from Table B]
    union all select email_address from [Not-In-Table-B]
    union all select SubscriberKey as email_address from ent.[HardBounces_DE]
    union all select SubscriberKey as email_address from ent.[DV_Complaint]
    union all select email_address from [Withdrawn_Non-Retargetable]
    union all select email_address from [DM Data To be Excluded from OE]
)
AND e.expiry_date = '7/20/2023 12:00:00 AM'
AND e.email_address like '%@gmail.com'
/* target: Offer_Extension_Warmup_Journey_Entry */
/* action: overwrite */
```

**Query 2**

```sql
SELECT
  e.email_address
, e.first_name
, e.last_name
, e.preapproved_amount
, e.promo_code
, e.expiry_date
FROM Offer_Extension_Warmup_Journey_Entry as e
/* action: update */
/* target: Offer_Extension_Journey_Entry */
```